# Rshiny subset data using selectinput including "all" option

Tags: r, shiny

In Rshiny UI I have two selectinputs years and tunnel:

```
selectInput("years", "Year", seq(min(df_map$jaar),max(df_map$jaar),1), selected = max(df_map$jaar), multiple = FALSE),
selectInput("tunnel", "Tunnel", c("ALL", sort(unique(df_map$tunnelnaam))), multiple = FALSE)
```

In Rshiny Server I would like to subset as follows so I can select ALL tunnels as well as a single tunnel:

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    if(input$tunnel == "ALL") {
      subset(df_map, jaar %in% input$years)
    }
    if(input$tunnel != "ALL") {
      subset(df_map, jaar %in% input$years & tunnelnaam %in% input$tunnel)
    }
  })
```

I am getting the following error when choosing ALL however:

```
addCircleMarkers requires non-NULL longitude/latitude values
```

It seems filteredData() is not working when ALL tunnels are selected. Does anyone have an idea how to select ALL tunnels as well as single tunnels in Rshiny? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: does one of the answers work for you?

Comment: downvote for ignoring any of the given answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it with a checkbox "Show all tunnels" in the UI:

UI:

```
checkboxInput("show_all_tunnels", "Show all tunnels", TRUE)
```

Server:

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    if(input$show_all_tunnels) df_map[df_map$jaar == input$years,] else df_map[df_map$jaar == input$years & df_map$tunnelnaam == input$tunnels,]
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it is hard to say anything without reproducible example and sample data!

I can just recommend to try:

```
filteredData <- reactive({
    if(input$tunnel == "ALL") {
      subset(df_map, jaar %in% input$years)
    else{
      subset(df_map, jaar %in% input$years & tunnelnaam %in% input$tunnel)
    }
  })
```

or

```
 filteredData <- reactive({
        if(input$tunnel != "ALL"){
          subset(df_map, jaar %in% input$years & tunnelnaam %in% input$tunnel)
        else{
subset(df_map, jaar %in% input$years)
        }
  })
```